# Have you ever encountered this kind of proof

Tags: proof-writing

Have you ever encoutered a proof like this one :

If $Q$ is true then $P$ is true.

If $Q$ is false then $P$ is true.

Therefore $P$ is true.

Comment: Well, yes... many times.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example: take $Q$ to be $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}\in\Bbb Q$, and $P$ to be $\exists a,\,b\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q(a^b\in\Bbb Q)$. If $Q$ is false ([it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem)), take $a=\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2},\,b=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond-Schneider_constant#Properties

Comment: Ohh I remember that one. If $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q} $ then we're done otherwise $ (\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2})^\sqrt{2}= \sqrt{2}^2 = 2 \in \mathbb{Q} $. Quite smart.

Answer (score 1):

[Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem#Euclid's_proof) is such a proof.